# Ajax Jquery call not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i'm trying to make a simple ajax request to the following URL. https://insightsoftwaresolutions.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=TES&issuetypeNames=Bug&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields

It receives the JSON response when i just put the URL on browser navigation bar and press enter but it's not working when i try to make a jquery ajax call. It's not having any console errors.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                url: 'https://insightsoftwaresolutions.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=TES&issuetypeNames=Bug&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'jsonp',

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        //displayCallResults(jqXHR);
                        alert("error");
                    }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the datatype:'jsonp' to datatype:'json'. Then i get the following error.

```
Origin http://localhost:3029 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: What is in the net tab?

Comment: It doesn't look like the said api is supporting jsonp

Comment: So, what is the error message and error code instead of just alert('error')? Also, have you used Fiddler to inspect the request and response? Have you tried POST instead of GET?

Comment: please add callback=? because it is necessary when want to get data through jsonp http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Comment: it's the client JSON parser having trouble parsing the response the result of the query is this {"expand":"projects","projects":[]}

Comment: Try to figure out what the error message shown on network tab of firebug. could help us more for troubleshooting.

Comment: @ArunPJohny please refer to my update

Comment: @MudaserAli i tried but did not work

Comment: One more thing whatever value is passed through callback you have to encapsulate your json object in that. like for example in php we use echo $_GET['callback'].'(' . json_encode($data).')'; Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053/simple-jquery-php-and-jsonp-example

Comment: I guess you can find solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: callbak is not mandatory using jQuery because jQuery itself if omitted undertakes d puts it.
The case is that the URL JSON is not returning anything because the array response 'projects' is empty.
Theoretically the request is ok.
Requests cross-platform work only with type JSONP

Comment: @WalterBarreiroNeto since the response is received, even though the array is empty i should ended up with "success" alert right? so why is it ended up receiving "error" alert?

Comment: is right, try removing the lines `cache: false,` and `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and let your code less error prone for we analyze. test this

Comment: JSON-P is no longer supported.  See [JIRA 6 notes](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Preparing+for+JIRA+6.0#PreparingforJIRA6.0-JSON-Pnolongersupported) and [Razaq Omar (Atlassian)'s response to a similar inquiry](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/138618/jira-rest-api-response-suddenly-stopped-sending-jsonp-getting-invalid-label-syntax-error).  JSONP client-side makes your applications insecure and Atlassian decided to protect you from taking the risk (helpful or not).

Comment: change to dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 2):

Your Server does not support [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295692/does-jsonp-require-server-modifications). Either change that

OR

Add headers at nginx to support CORS on the server side. OR you can add the CORS header on server side.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Once you do that you can access your code using simple

```
$.getJSON(url).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response); //here's your response
});
```