# Error in CORS ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, json, jsonp, cors

In php i do `echo json_encode($dump);`

If echo it out using php i get `{"load":"0.64 0.58 0.52 2\/361 12978\n","procs":"8\n"}`

Than i make CORS Request using `dataType:jsonp`

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'http://labs.isaumya.com/loadtest/load',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

I get this error on the console:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAxx6.png]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7D5V/1/)

Comment: in case of jsonp u need to use callback as a response.

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with JSON, not JSONP. `dataType: "jsonp",` should be `dataType: "json",`

You can remove the `data` parameter entirely if your server outputs the correct content-type header for JSON (`application/json`).

---

JSONP is a hack to work around the Same Origin Policy from before CORS was designed and implemented by browsers. CORS is the modern approach to making cross origin requests. You use it **instead of** JSONP.

---

Both CORS and JSONP are technologies that must be supported by the server. `http://labs.isaumya.com/loadtest/load` doesn't appear to support either. You will have to modify the server if you want it to supply data in JSONP format or grant permission with CORS.

---

Unrelated to your actual problem:

You have no `data` parameter so you aren't sending JSON *to* to the server, remove the `ContentType` parameter. Since you aren't POSTing any data, you should probably be making a GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: if i use `json` than it will not serve `CORS` Request .

Comment: @user3527203 — CORS is the modern alternative to JSONP. You don't use JSONP for a CORS request.

Comment: see --> http://jsfiddle.net/w7D5V/2/ i made changes you say but still getting error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://labs.isaumya.com/loadtest/load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1`

Comment: As mentioned in the answer: "You will have to modify the server if you want it to supply data in JSONP format or grant permission with CORS"

Comment: how to modify server for jsonp request ?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295692/does-jsonp-require-server-modifications)

Comment: @user3527203 You need to modify the header

Comment: @RahilWazir — That's for CORS, not for JSONP.

Comment: @Quentin is correct -- @user3527203 -- CORS requests are not the same as jsonp. To allow JSONP, you must configure your server to pad json results with a/the function name passed via your query string. `JSONP === padded json`