# cannot get REST response using $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

Below is my method

```
function getCurrentUserName() 
{
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8099/rest/prototype/1/space/ds",
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType: "jsonp",  
    success: function(resp){  
        alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp.name + "'");  
        },
    error:function(e){
    alert("Error"+e)
    }
    });
    });
}
```

I am calling this on a button click , I do not see any alert , when i type the url on the browser I get the response in xml .but i do not get the response in the script.
Can someone please help me with this ? Am i missing something here ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked in the developer tools if the request is actually made?

Comment: add error function to and put laert to check if error coming

Comment: yes the request is made its shown in the browser console . it returns  [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 31ms]

Comment: can you show your controller method which process your request

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Does your server know how to handle `jsonp`? It needs to call the function name given as part of the query string with the response data, since it's just loading a script and not actually doing an AJAX request.

Comment: @Nirmal I have added a error function which give an alert ..

Comment: @EhsanSajjad please find my update script . Can you please help me how to check what is the error

Comment: Update what is the error message

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme can you please guide me how to check if my server knows to handle Jsonp .. can you give a snippet example

Comment: @AvinashKothamasu error is Error[object Object]

Comment: You can try alert("Error "+e.message); to get the exact error message. Then I think we can figure out some cause of the issue

Comment: @Nirmal I get Error undefined

Comment: try like this: error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295692/does-jsonp-require-server-modifications

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i get the error as .. "parsererror" "jQuery15209408919270726295_1398151013877 was not called"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a JSON parse error.

Try with the `json` instead of `jsonp`

```
function getCurrentUserName() 
{
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8099/rest/prototype/1/space/ds",
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(resp){  
        alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp.name + "'");  
        },
    error:function(e){
    alert("Error"+e)
    }
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: I get the same error .. the data returned by the rest call is in xml format . I need it in Json .
I am also trying the below code
  '$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://localhost:8099/rest/prototype/1/space/ds",
  data: {},
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml){
    var clientid = $(xml).find('avatarUrl').first().text();
    alert(""+clientid);
  }   
});'